# Download a file from BlobFile attribute

Tags: genexus

I'm testing a bit with blobfile data type in Genexus but I can't understand how to download a file I have previously saved in it, the wiki page didn't help. The attribute has not methods or thing that looks useful. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a proc with HTTP call protocol and returning the file.

Suppose you have a transaction with this structure:

FilesToDownloadId*

FilesToDownloadFile - Defined as BlobFile

Suppose you have a Webpanel with a grid showing a list of files (both attributtes) and &Download variable is just a char variable to use the "link" function.

```
Event Load
    &Download="Download"
    &Download.Link=DownloadFile.Link(FilesToDownloadId)
Endevent
```

DownloadFile is a proc with "Call Protocol" property set to HTTP.

This proc is:

Rules: parm( IN:FilesToDownloadId );

```
for each
    &HttpResponse.AddHeader(!'Content-Type',  FilesToDownloadFile.FileType)
    &HttpResponse.AddHeader(!'Content-Disposition', !'attachment; filename=' + FilesToDownloadFile.FileName+"."+FilesToDownloadFile.FileType)
    &blob=FilesToDownloadfile
    &HttpResponse.AddFile(&Blob)
endfor
```

Vars:

&Blob - Blob

&ContentType - Varchar(40)

&HttpResponse - HTTPResponse

Comment: It's working, thank you. Not a fan of how the blobfile is renamed (the random string after the "_" , but I can save the name in another position and use it to rename the file)